# Unable to run Docker Toolbox on windows 10 home even after enabling virtualization from BIOS settings

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, docker-machine, boot2docker

On running docker quickstart terminal I get the following error:

> Running pre-create checks... Error with pre-create check: "This
>   computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is
>   mandatory" Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if
>   machine default exists´... Press any key to continue...

I have tried everything from enabling the virtualization from the bios setting to reinstalling the toolbox but this error doesn't seem to go away. I read that since Windows 10 home doesn't support Hyper-V so one has to use docker toolbox but still this error is coming. Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to read this thread? [Machine’s Issue](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4271)

Personally I managed to solve the issue by using this PS’s command (considering my Win 10 is Home edition):

> PS> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

Answer (score 1):

This is the fix for Windows 10 Home Users

Open C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh with an Editor

Replace line 71 from

"${DOCKER_MACHINE}" create -d virtualbox $PROXY_ENV "${VM}"

to

"${DOCKER_MACHINE}" create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-no-vtx-check $PROXY_ENV "${VM}"

Open Docker Quickstart Terminal.
Done :)