# This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled

Tags: linux, windows, docker, docker-machine, kitematic

When I'm trying to create a default machine through Kitematic, I'm always receiving the same error message. It tells me that "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled", even if the task manager is showing me that the virtualization is on. Any ideas how can I fix this problem?

```
Command failed: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe -D create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default,Docker Machine Version: 0.16.1, build cce350d7,Found binary path at C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe,Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox,Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:50871,() Calling .GetVersion,Using API Version 1,() Calling .SetConfigRaw,() Calling .GetMachineName,(flag-lookup) Calling .GetMachineName,(flag-lookup) Calling .DriverName,(flag-lookup) Calling .GetCreateFlags,Found binary path at C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe,Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox,Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:50873,() Calling .GetVersion,Using API Version 1,() Calling .SetConfigRaw,() Calling .GetMachineName,(default) Calling .GetMachineName,(default) Calling .DriverName,(default) Calling .GetCreateFlags,(default) Calling .SetConfigFromFlags,Reading certificate data from C:\Users\Alex Wieland\.docker\machine\certs\ca.pem,Decoding PEM data...,Parsing certificate...,Reading certificate data from C:\Users\Alex Wieland\.docker\machine\certs\cert.pem,Decoding PEM data...,Parsing certificate...,(default) Calling .PreCreateCheck,(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe --version,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | 6.0.10r132072,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | Hyper-V is not installed.,Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory",open C:\Users\Alex Wieland\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\Logs\VBox.log: The system cannot find the path specified.,notifying bugsnag: [Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"],
```

Comment: Consider using Docker Desktop instead of Docker Toolbox. Related, possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703047/unable-to-run-docker-toolbox-on-windows-10-home-even-after-enabling-virtualizati?rq=1

Comment: *"Any ideas how can I fix this problem?"* - The output of the command seems to be pretty clear: *"This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"*. Enable virtualization in the BIOS/UEFI. Probably a better topic for [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: The strange thing was that the virtualization was already enabled. Upgraded now to Windows Pro, so this problem became irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it with this command:

docker-machine create default --virtualbox-no-vtx-check

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have HyperV disabled, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50403200/6309):

As seen in [`docker/machine` issue 4271](https://github.com/https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4271)

> Hyper-V relies on hardware virtualization support (e.g. Intel VT-x and AMD-V) to run virtual machines. Typically, once Hyper-V is installed, the hypervisor hides this capability from guest virtual machines, preventing guests virtual machines from installing Hyper-V (and many other hypervisors, for that matter).

Since your command-line is using VirtualBox, you can't have both HyperV and VirtualBox active at the same time (although [you can switch from one to the other](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx)).

Comment: Just one minute ago I also saw this information. For unknown reasons, I was convinced that Hyper V is needed to get Docker Toolbox to work.
But now when I'm starting the Oracle Vm default machine, it throws the error "VT-x/Amd-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system".
Also Kitematic can't create the default machine.

Comment: Probably I misunderstood here something, the virtualization in the bios needs to be on and hyperV disabled right? Unfortunately the hyper V option is not visible within the windows features due to the Windows 10 Home license.

Comment: As in here? https://localbyflywheel.com/community/t/virtualization-is-enabled-from-bios-but-still-getting-vt-x-amd-v-enabled-error/12031/4 (did you reset Kinematic: https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/2193#issuecomment-330366643)

Comment: Updated now to Windows 10 Pro, the 
error message annoyed me ^^ Were no problems when I installed Docker Desktop.
Thanks for your help

Comment: @ProV OK, strange: https://thewebspark.com/2019/04/02/how-to-enable-virtualization-in-bios-of-windows-10-home-hp-systems-solved/ shows that Docker Desktop does not support Windows Home Edition indeed. But Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 Home (with enabling Virtualization in the BIOS) should have worked.

Comment: The reason why Docker Desktop does not support Windows Home is that Hyper V is required, which is only available at Windows 10 Pro and higher. Yes really strange, on my old Laptop i did the same and there it worked.